# Not retrieving CurrentUser specific data from Firebase - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm having an issue with retrieving certain data from Firebase and i tried it many ways. I want to get for instance, **city** data from thee current user. Instead of getting city name, I get 'Query snapshot' value on city watch list.

```
  void addToFb() async {
final User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
final uid = user.uid;
final city = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(uid)
    .collection("city")
    .get();


dbRef.push().set({
  "name": nameController.text,
  "author": authorController.text,
  "city": city,
  "category": dropdownValue,
  "publisher": publisherController.text,
  "years": yearsController.text,
  "info": infoController.text,
  "ownerid": uid
```

Comment: Your code is writing to the Realtime Database, but it is reading from Cloud Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, have their own APIs, and data from one doesn't show up in the other.

Comment: If i understand correctly @frank, i need to change FirebaseFirestore into FirebaseData?

Comment: You need to change one of them, so that reading and writing happen with the same database. Which one that is, is up to you to decide. If you need help choosing, consider https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore

Answer (score 2):

You need to first determine if you're using the Realtime Database or Firestore.

**`FirebaseDatabase`** refers to the Firebase Realtime Database and doesn't have collections.  Its usage would look like this:

`FirestoreDatabase().reference('Users')`

**`FirebaseFirestore`** is probably what you're looking for as it refers to Firestore and has collections.

`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users')`

Comment: Thanks, for your time. But now when i fixed it i get **city** value on watch list "Query shot" instead of the actual value of the city name.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is looking for a collection called *city* under your user document. However, it sounds like you just need the *city* field within the document.

Try this:

```
final userDocument = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Users')
    .doc(uid)
    .get();
    
final userData = userDocument.data();
final city = userData['city'];
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tried your code, but now i get **The getter isn't defined for the class 'InkResponse State'** error. That was unexpected and instead function, which is responsible for catching the errors it doesn't appear and show infinite loading animation @David Waiting